# What is the craic with ContainerViews? (Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object)

Tags: ember.js

All,

I have searched around for an answer to this but have yet to find a good explanation and solution.  Hopefully, you can help.

I have a route that renders an Ember.ContainerView (as opposed to a standard Ember.View).  When I transition away from this route and then back to it (either via the back button, a link-helper or just changing the url) I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object
```

I understand that a high level reason for this is that when we transition away from the route with the ContainerView, it's `childViews` are marked as destroyed.  When we transition back to the route, the problem has something to do with Ember trying to set the `childViews` back to the destroyed instances.

I'm not exactly clear but that is the vague understanding I currently have.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. **Can you please correct my understanding of this problem if it is not correct?**
2. **Can you please tell me how to fix this error?**

For your convenience, I have created a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/riruz/1) for your viewing pleasure.  To replicate the error, open your JS console, click on the `Go to Route two` link, then click on the `Go to index` link.  Now check your logs.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix:  http://jsbin.com/jumoy/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I have encountered this problem before.  I can't say I truly understand it at a very detailed level, but here is the general problem.  When you are defining your container view, it is actually creating that subview when you define it, not when you create an instance of the view.  This means that your childview 'initial' is only being created one time, and thats when the file is initialled parsed and the ContainerView is defined.  When ember cleans this childview up, it is not gone for ever and 'initial' will always be equal to a cleaned up view.

By setting 'initial' as a property, it will be created every time a new instance of your container view is rendered, and therefore a new childview will be created and accessible.

So moral of the story, try not to create objects in definitions of controllers/views.  Instead create properties that return the creation of that object.

Hope this helps and makes sense.

UPDATE::

I have edited the jsbin to show you on a deeper level what is happening and why it isn't working.  To see the effect uncomment the second ContainerView and comment out the first, you will notice in the console logs that the second time you go to the twoRoute, it has marked that initial property as state: destroying for the view.

http://jsbin.com/jumoy/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Mate, thanks for the great answer.  You know what?  I was doing something very similar to your solution but I must have missed something as I couldn't get it to work.

And in terms of my understanding, that's pretty much how I understood things to happen except the thing that you really cleared up is

**"This means that your childview 'initial' is only being created one time, and thats when the file is initialled parsed and the ContainerView is defined."**

That's the part I was missing.  But makes everything else make sense.  Thanks again mate

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `Ember.Instrumentation` namespace for publishing your events and `Ember.subscribe` to listen to them in your code, **when you publish events, it stack all the subscribers and call them even when they are destroyed.**

so basically, when for example your route is destroyed which is running subscribe statements it will fail and give above error.

Here is a solution to this problem:  Use `Ember.Instrumentation.reset()` to remove previous subscribers which are destroyed. This solution helped me in acceptance tests where app was destroyed after tests are finished. 
I wrote `Ember.Instrumentation.reset()` in `startApp` function of `module-for-acceptance.js` and it worked.

Hope that helps.